# Votedown por resposta conter conteúdo que não pertence às tags da pergunta, válido ou não?

Tags: debate

Estava olhando meu histórico de respostas e acabei me deparando com [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39134/limitar-div-html/39159#39159). O op fez uma pergunta com baixa qualidade e recebeu alguns votedown, porém entendendo a sua dúvida redigi uma resposta que resolvia o problema.

Recebi um votedown pela resposta conter um código `css` (mais especificadamente, por eu não ter usado a tag `<style>`) e as tags da pergunta serem `php` e `html`.

Afinal, esse votedown foi correto e possui fundamento ou não? Esse "erro" pode ser atribuído à minha resposta ou à pergunta que aparentemente não possuía as tags ideais?

Comment: Caso o voto tenha sido realmente do mesmo usuário que comentou (não temos como saber quem foi), e pelo motivo que você citou, não faz nenhum sentido. Porém, cada um é livre para votar como quiser, contanto que não persiga outros usuários com votos em série.

Comment: O pessoal vota estranho mesmo. Como a pergunta teve negativos, pode ser que respingou em você, talvez nem seja quem comentou. Você mesmo fez uma pergunta, uma resposta focou no que você perguntou e você a aceitou. Mas ela tinha umas verdades que o pessoal não gosta de ouvir. Aí o que aconteceu? As outras que responderam apenas tangencialmente o que foi perguntado sem detalhar ou mesmo fundamentar o ponto central tiveram mais votos. Então o pessoal vota com critérios pessoais que só eles entendem.

Comment: Você não pos a tag style e nem falou pra salvar em arquivo separado, apenas disse quais seriam as propriedades de estilo necessárias. Creio que o comentário lá seja completamente impertintente. Entretanto, isso não guarda necessariamente relação com o voto negativo, que pode ser facilmente por qualquer outro motivo e de qualquer outro usuário (ou seja, aqui você é que está levantando uma suposição meio complicada, da mesma forma que no comentário da sua resposta).